# T = char can't be deduced for std::basic_string<T> foo = "foo"?

Tags: c++

**Question:**
In the code below, template argument type deduction seems to fail for the first sample, but not for the second sample. I don't understand why the first sample fails to deduce `T = char`. I would think that `T` can be deduced when converting from `"foo"` to `std::bacis_string<T>`, but even if that didn't work, I provide the second function argument which, I would think, would clearly constrain `T` to `char`. *Why* does it fail?

**[Does not work](http://ideone.com/ctF0oG):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
void print(const std::basic_string<T>& a, const std::basic_string<T>& b)
{
    std::cout << a << b << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string bar = "bar";
    print("foo", bar);
}
```

**Error:**

```
string.cpp:14:5: error: no matching function for call to 'print'
    print("foo", bar);
    ^~~~~
string.cpp:6:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, char_traits<type-parameter-0-0>,
      allocator<type-parameter-0-0> >' against 'char const[4]'
void print(const std::basic_string<T>& a, const std::basic_string<T>& b)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

**[Works](http://ideone.com/5Hv7i7):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
void print(const std::basic_string<T>& a, const std::basic_string<T>& b)
{
    std::cout << a << b << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string foo = "foo";
    std::string bar = "bar";
    print(foo, bar);
}
```

Comment: Well asked and formatted question, +1.

Comment: I would say that it is because `"foo"`'s type is not `std::string` but `const char*` which the compiler is not willing/able to convert to `std::string`... This is a suspicion and I hope someone can offer something more concrete. Is `std::string`'s constructor that accepts `const char*` marked as explicit?

Comment: @nonsensickle: But why not? If I explicitly state the template type by calling `print<char>("foo", bar)` it works, so the compiler is happy to convert `const char[4]` to `std::basic_string<char>` in that case. But why not the first case?

Comment: @nonsensickle: Nope, it's not. I checked before asking this question. [There's only one constructor that's explicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

Comment: @Cornstalks I don't know, but I'm keen to find the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is a conversion is required here. To deduce `T`, the compiler would have to inspect all possible instantiations of `std::basic_string` and see which of them can be constructed from a `const char*` (or actually `const char (&)[4]`). That's of course not possible, as there's infinitely many of them. The reason why it has to inspect all and cannot just scan the primary template definition for constructors taking `const char*` or `const char(&)[4]` is that for some `T`, `std::basic_string<T>` could be partially or completely specialised, and the members of those specialisations have no relationship to the members of the primary template.

Comment: But why doesn't the second parameter constrain `T = char` (which would then mean the compiler only has to check for one conversion for the first parameter)? Also, I'm not sure the compiler would have to check all possible `T`s, as the compiler could check which constructors accept a `const T*` and find that there's [only one (#5)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), and deduce from `const char*` and `const T*` that `T = char`. Couldn't it?

Comment: @Cornstalks For "inspecting all `T`s," I've expanded the answer. For why the constraint `T = char` doesn't work, I can't find a standard quote now, but IIRR, the reason is that `T` is not in a non-deduced context in the first parameter, and so for deduction to succeed, the `T` deduced from all arguments must match. And there's no way to deduce it from the `cosnt char[4]`.

Comment: Ah, yeah, good point about potential specializations! +1. Interestingly, I'm working around this issue by doing `print(const std::basic_string<typename std::basic_string<T>::value_type>& a, const std::basic_string<T>& b)`, which works fine.

Comment: @Cornstalks Yes, this puts the `T` in the first parameter into a non-deduced context, so it doesn't try deduction there. Any other way of forcing a non-deduced context would work as well. Of course, that will fail if you call `print(bar, "foo")` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the short version of an answer.

The compiler has `char const[]` and is looking to convert that to `std::basic_string<T>`.  How does it work out what `T` is?   *You* know that you want to match `T = char` but the compiler does not know that.

It could look for a constructor `basic_string<T>(char const *)`, for example. Even if that exists, it still does not say what `T` should be.

The compiler doesn't iterate over all possible typenames it knows about and attempt `basic_string<T>` for each one, and then see if there is a matching constructor.

Similar example:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    Foo(T t) {}
};

int main()
{
    Foo(0);    // error, can't deduce Foo<int>
}
```

Comment: I can't see how this example is similar, since there's never any template argument deduction with class templates.